# How to move a MySQL DB to a new structure?! Any Tools?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to move a old database with an old structure to a new one.

Both Databases are MySQL Databases (InnoDB).
The Information is basically the same but has been moved to different tables and stuff like that.

What I'm searching now is a tool which helps me to move the data to the new structure. Something like a data mapping tool which generates the php code or something like that for me.

Is there something like that or do you know a better way to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into ETL (Extract Transform Load) tools. Popular (and free) ones are Talend Open Studio and the Pentaho Suite.

But don't expect miracles.

The migration of a complex database schema is not a simple task and you won't find any easy point and click tools. You will need to put a lot of thinking into it.

Answer (score 1):

What about [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

It's designed to do stuff like this.

You can setup connection to existing DB and do reverse-engineer.

Then change schema (renaming tables, creating/removing columns, etc...).

Last step is forward engineering to deploy your new schema to DB.

It has self-explaining GUI, so no problem at all.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench